# React component export as PNG with a transparent background

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `exportComponentAsPNG` function from `react-component-export-image` lib:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-export-image

`exportComponentAsPNG(node, {fileName, html2CanvasOptions})`

The function works great if I pass just a component. But I can't make it work with optional `params` and produce an image with transparent background (maybe I'm missing something about optional parameters conversion of JS in general). So I tried to pass a `backgroundColor` option, which, I think, should help me with getting a transparent background. What I've already tried:

- `exportComponentAsPNG(node, backgroundColor = null);`
- `exportComponentAsPNG(node, backgroundColor: null);`
- `exportComponentAsPNG(node, { backgroundColor: null });`

I could specify `backgroundColor` with the previous version of `react-component-export-image` API, but now I'm getting lost with the new syntax.

Comment: I guess the second one will make a syntax error in your source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the docs

#### [How to Upgrade](https://github.com/salman-monetate/react-component-export-image/blob/8496a80f06b6bba49021e32ce8afe8e8f9bcf9a5/README.md#how-to-upgrade)

> The previous way of using an export looked like this:

exportComponentAsJPEG(node, fileName, type, backgroundColor, options)

- The new way: pass node & an optional object with only the fields you need.
- backgroundColor is no longer accepted in this main object, but is accepted in the "html2CanvasOptions" object, which is passed directly to html2canvas

if you say it've worked before with backgorundColor equals to null you should call it this way

```js
exportComponentAsPNG(node, { html2CanvasOptions: {backgroundColor: null} })
```

you can also take look at its implementation [src-code](https://github.com/salman-monetate/react-component-export-image/blob/8496a80f06b6bba49021e32ce8afe8e8f9bcf9a5/index.js#L64)